# How do I remove the "0-0 0" from this time difference column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting, window-functions, partitioning

I have a data set that pulls the difference of time between each entered and deleted order. However with this code I get an output that reads 0-0 0 and the time difference. I would like to remove the 0-0 0 if possible.

```
SELECT CAST(Left(time, 8) AS time) AS time, 
       coalesce(buyer_order_id, SELLER_ORDER_ID) AS order_id,
       CAST(left(time, 8) AS time) - lag(CAST(Left(time, 8) AS time), 1) 
        OVER (partition by coalesce(buyer_order_id, SELLER_ORDER_ID) order by time) AS time_difference
FROM orders.sheet1 
WHERE message_type = "ENTER" OR message_Type = "DELETE" 
order by order_id
```

sample output:

```
time     order_id  message_type time_difference
01:56:26 267       ENTER        null
04:20:24 267       DELETE       0-0 0 2:23:58   
01:57:00 268       ENTER        null
03:31:57 268       DELETE       0-0 0 1:34:57
```

tried many variations of replace and right functions but have been unsuccessful since the output is a time one and not a string.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: please tag your DBMS and provide some sample data. Your query is a little confusing it seems to refer to *columns* named Enter and Delete

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: db is google- bigquery, since this data is somewhat sensitive i cannot send the full sample data but will edit to include the message_type column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you try below ?

```sql
SELECT *,
       TIME (
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_difference),
         EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_difference),
         EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_difference)
       ) AS time_diff
  FROM (
    SELECT CAST(Left(time, 8) AS time) AS time, 
          coalesce(buyer_order_id, SELLER_ORDER_ID) AS order_id,
          CAST(left(time, 8) AS time) - lag(CAST(Left(time, 8) AS time), 1) 
            OVER (partition by coalesce(buyer_order_id, SELLER_ORDER_ID) order by time) AS time_difference
    FROM orders.sheet1 
  WHERE message_type = "ENTER" OR message_Type = "DELETE" 
) order by order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In bigquery do this:

```
TIME(CAST(left(time, 8) AS time) - lag(CAST(Left(time, 8))
```

---

You can use convert if this is SQL server (you want 14 or 114)

```
CONVERT(time, CAST(left(time, 8) AS time) - lag(CAST(Left(time, 8), 114)
```

More details documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Wish i could, but this is bigquery so unfortunately wont work

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider the type of the `time_difference` column. BigQuery has the [TIME_DIFF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#time_diff) function which returns an INT64.
Here's an example:

```
WITH
  -- sample data
  tmp AS (
  SELECT
    t,
    oid,
    msg_type
  FROM
    UNNEST( ["01:56:26", "04:20:24", "01:57:00", "03:31:57"]) t
  WITH
  OFFSET
    o1
  LEFT JOIN
    UNNEST([267, 267, 268, 268]) oid
  WITH
  OFFSET
    o2
  ON
    o1 = o2
  LEFT JOIN
    UNNEST(["ENTER", "DELETE", "ENTER", "DELETE"]) msg_type
  WITH
  OFFSET
    o3
  ON
    o2 = o3 ),

  -- calculate the lag
  lags AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(LEFT(t, 8) AS time) AS time,
    oid,
    msg_type,
    LAG(CAST(LEFT(t, 8) AS time), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY oid ORDER BY t) AS time_lag
  FROM
    tmp
  WHERE
    msg_type = "ENTER"
    OR msg_type = "DELETE"
  ORDER BY
    oid)

-- time difference in seconds
SELECT
  time,
  oid AS order_id,
  msg_type AS message_type,
  TIME_DIFF(time, time_lag, SECOND) AS time_difference_seconds
FROM lags;
```